# Qual é a coplexidade de minha solução?

Tags: javascript, complexidade-de-algoritmo, set

Tenho o seguinte problema de computação:

```
Given an array arr of integers, check if there exists two integers N and M such that N is the double of M ( i.e. N = 2 * M).

More formally check if there exists two indices i and j such that :

i != j
0 <= i, j < arr.length
arr[i] == 2 * arr[j]
 

Example 1:

Input: arr = [10,2,5,3]
Output: true
Explanation: N = 10 is the double of M = 5,that is, 10 = 2 * 5.
Example 2:

Input: arr = [7,1,14,11]
Output: true
Explanation: N = 14 is the double of M = 7,that is, 14 = 2 * 7.
Example 3:

Input: arr = [3,1,7,11]
Output: false
Explanation: In this case does not exist N and M, such that N = 2 * M.
 

Constraints:

2 <= arr.length <= 500
-10^3 <= arr[i] <= 10^3
```

Resumindo tenho que validar se uma vetor possui um número que possui seu dobro.

Já possuo a solução que funciona:

```
var checkIfExist = function(arr) {
    const set = new Set();
    
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
      const currValue = arr[i];
      
      if(set.has(currValue)) {
        return true
      }
      set.add(currValue / 2);
      set.add(currValue * 2);
    }
  
  return false;
};
```

Já resolvi o problema, porém estou na duvida da complexidade da minha solução. Não sei se o `set` é O(1) neste caso. Para mim a solução é O(N^2), porém estão me dizendo que é O(N). Alguém pode me explicar a complexidade do `set`.

Comment: Set não é ordenado, então, deve ser uma hashtable, portanto, O(1). A sua solução itera o array com um for, então, ela é O(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O loop do algoritmo dá a resposta. Na pior das hipóteses, a condição de saída `set.has(currValue)` nunca será verdadeira. Isso faz com que cada elemento do array seja visitado ao menos uma vez. E não poderia ser diferente, já que é impossível garantir que não existe um par `(M, N)` que satisfaça `N = 2 * M` sem visitar cada elemento.

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
  const currValue = arr[i];
  
  if(set.has(currValue)) {
    return true
  }
  set.add(currValue / 2);
  set.add(currValue * 2);
}
```

> Não sei se o set é O(1) neste caso.

Lembre-se que um HashMap bem implementado possui um tempo de acesso O(1).
Mesmo que você supor que o Set do Javascript garanta esse tempo de acesso, e é preciso verificar se a especificação do Set garante isso, você está acessando o Set até N vezes. Logo, O(N).